# Factorization of a ring morphism for artinian rings

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $(R,m)$ be a complete local $k$-algebra. Let $A$ be a local artinian algebra with residue field $k$. Then, since $A$ is artinian, any map $f:R \rightarrow A$ factorizes as $R \rightarrow R/m^n \rightarrow A $ for any positive integer $n.$ Can someone explain why we have such a factorization? (Maybe $f$ has to be a local homomorphism?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $f$ should be assumed to be local.

Then $f(\mathfrak{m}) \subseteq \mathfrak{m}_A$ and since $\mathfrak{m}_A$ is nilpotent, the same is true for $f(\mathfrak{m})$. But if $f(\mathfrak{m})^n=0$, we have $\mathfrak{m}^n \subseteq \ker(f)$, and the factorization follows.

Comment: So then there exists some $n$, but not all $n$ work?

Comment: Of course not all $n$ work.